# Mouse is freezing randomly in TF2 and Civ5

Tags: civilization-5, technical-issues, team-fortress-2

My mouse keeps freezing in place at random times when I'm playing a game. It's happened in TF2 4 times already, and it's happened once when I was playing Civ 5. The mouse cursor moves to the middle of the screen, even when I ALT+TAB out, however the light on the bottom of the mouse is still on, and it goes back to normal. It has yet to happen outside of a game.

If anyone has experienced this or has a solution, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, alt+tab on the desktop the mouse still doesn't work at the desktop screen?

Comment: Yes, however In did not close the game.

Comment: Is this a Razer mouse by chance?

Comment: Microsoft USB. My keyboard is though. Could I be accidentally pressing something? I was just playing and it happened again.

Comment: Does this happen on any other Steam games? Could be the overlay.

Comment: try a steelseries sensei RAW...they are the best mice out there that you can get for your money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, it was my USB port. The 2 USB ports on the back of my PC must be sketchy somehow. If someone knows if there's a fix for that, that would be great, but it's the port.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere a while ago I saw someone update their DirectX and it seemed to correct the issue.

Unrelated to TF2, I know that sometimes a hidden popup would cause my computer to freeze up. I eventually found out it was a memory problem, and when I corrected that issue, everything went back to normal.

Comment: I just played Civ 5 and I know that has something to do with DirectX, but the mouse froze up in Civ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas you might try:

-Try unplugging and replugging your mouse, using canned air to blow out the port and the usb connector, or plugging the mouse into a different port

-Consider cleaning the laser or trackball of your mouse

-Disable your Windows key on your keyboard

-Try disabling Windows Aero or other 3d/graphical effects

-Check your mouse settings in Control Panel or if you are using a laptop check your power settings because your usb ports might be powering down while gaming.

-Disable Windows popups

-Disable sticky keys

-Update all your drivers specifically mouse and video

-Check your games for updates or verify integrity of game cache

-Check your in-game mouse settings for inconsistencies